# sending email thru smtp, gives 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: smtp, encode, nonetype

This is my code:

```py
import os
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib


smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"
port = 587  # For starttls
sender_email = "sender@mail.com"
email_receiver = 'receiver@mail.com'
password = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
subject = "Hello"
body = """
Can you make it today?
"""
em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = sender_email
em['To'] = email_receiver
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body)

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Try to log in to server and send email
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo() 
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo() 
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    
    server.sendmail('sender@mail.com', 'receiver@mail.com', em.as_string())
   
    print('Mail sent')
except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

I get this error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Where is my mistake?

Tried searching for 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' but couldn't relate other answers to my code.

Comment: Python prints a stacktrace with a line where the error occured, read it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know either why you were downvoted. This is a easy to understand question with a [mcve]. Of course, like @tla says, a stacktrace would be helpful. (Why are you running this in a jupyter notebook anyway? I never worked with them and thought they were mostly data science tools, and I wouldn't consider sending email too dat-sciency.)

Comment: That's what I install when started my learning process and since then I've been using it.
What are you using? Or have recommendations?

Comment: You can use any text editor for Python, or an IDE like pycharm. When you run your code without the extra layers of Jupyter, it may be faster and easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up your ssl stuff. You either connect on the unencrypted default SMTP port 25 and then use the `STARTTLS` command to switch to an encrypted connection, *OR* you connect with a tls connection on port 465 and then you don't send the `STARTTLS`. The later is done using a [`SMTP_SSL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) object rather than the plain `SMTP`.

That said, I don't see where exactly the `encode` came from; probably from the bowels of the SMTP library.

This works for me:

```py
import os
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib

smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"
port = 25 # plain connection, we'll switch to tls later with starttls
sender_email = 'me@example.org'
email_receiver = sender_email
password = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = sender_email
em['To'] = email_receiver
em['Subject'] = "Hello"
em.set_content("Can you make it today?")

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Try to log in to server and send email
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, email_receiver, em.as_string())
print('Mail sent')
```

I've used a `with` block so that the connection gets closed automatically. I also removed the `except` so that I get a full stack trace of any exception instead of just printing an error message. I've shortened some of your original variables for brevity.

Comment: This is wrong. Port 25 is for email servers, they use it to deliver the emails. You are not supposed to use it for sending the emails as a client. Port 587 is for submission using plain or STARTTLS connections and port 465 is for implicit TLS connections.

Comment: @tla Nope, your local email client can also connect to a mail server on port 25. The server doesn't care if another server or a mail user agent connects, as long as it speaks smtp. See section 5 in [RFC 3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207) regarding `starttls`, which also mentions port 25. Of course, each server can chose to run on any port, so my answer boils down to either connect encrypted and skip the `starttls` or connect plain on the well-known port for smtp (which is 25), and use `starttls` to switch to an encrypted connection.

Comment: RFC 3207 provides an example of mail.example.com email server connecting to mail.imc.org email server, that is why it is using port 25. Clients connecting to office365.com are supposed to use port 587: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353 Port 25 is probably provided for compatibility, but it is a bad idea to configure your client to use port 25 because it is blocked on many networks, e.g. if you are traveling and using Wi-Fi on a laptop.

Comment: @tls Just try it... `telnet smtp.office365.com 25`.

Comment: @Robert I know the port is open on the server, but it is not documented and some ISPs block it from the client side. 587 is also open but more reliable, port 587 was not the problem and there is no reason to change it.